# URL masking in nginx

Tags: nginx, alias, masking

My page's styles point to the following URL:

```
https://example.com/assets/styles/theme-1.css?v=11
```

However, the actual `styles` are sitting on

```
/var/www/somedomain.com/html/z/assets/styles/theme-1.css?v=11
```

I need for the URL from the top to point to the above path.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work

```
location /assets {
   alias /var/www/somedomain.com/html/z/assets;
}
```

I have also tried using `proxy_pass` with no positive results.

Any clues to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The url path structure is the same as the file directory, so you can just use `root` as the following:

```
location /assets {
    root /var/www/somedomain.com/html/z;
}
```